# Lua-Corona SDK-Outlaw [Stupid] Creating a table issue

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I have started learning corona recently, and I'm having a trouble finding the problem in defining a correct list.

My exercise is to create a PickerWheel, for what I'm defining my Y/M/D list/array/table

This is my input:

```
local meses= {
    "Enero",
    "Febrero",
    "Marzo",
    "Abril",
    "Mayo",
    "Junio",
    "Julio",
    "Agosto",
    "Septiembre",
    "Octubre",
    "Noviembre",
    "Diciembre"
}

    --LINE OF ERROR HERE
local dias  {}

  for i=1, 31 do
    dias[i]=i
  end

local anos  {}

  for j=1, 64 do
    anos[j]=1969+j
  end
```

What outlaw throws me back is:

```
main.lua:(--LINE OF ERROR HERE):unexpected symbol near '{'
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `local dias {}` should be `local dias = {}`. You can learn this syntax from any tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your table initializations like this:

```
local dias  = {}
local anos = {}
```

Comment: Thank you!Will pay more attention to typographical comments.